# W3C Validator offline on localhost by ajax

Tags: javascript, w3c, w3c-validation, adobe-brackets

I use to programming Brackets text editor and I have already installed W3C validator but it working while I'm online but offine not. I try install https://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html and I running to localhost:8888 but brackets's extension connecting only via ajax (javascript). Is possible send ajax like to original W3C website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker (validator) here. Yes it is possible to send an ajax request to a local instance of the current checker. To use [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to do it and get JSON-formatted results back:

```js
var checkerUrl = "http://localhost:8888/?out=json"
fetch(document.location.href)
.then(function(currentDoc) { return currentDoc.text(); })
.then(function(htmlSource) {
    fetch(
        checkerUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        body: htmlSource,
        headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "text/html;charset=utf-8" })
    })
    .then(function(checkerResponse) { return checkerResponse.json(); })
    .then(function(jsonOutput) {
        console.dir(jsonOutput.messages);
    })
});
```

That shows the basic steps to follow to deliver the request in the way the checker expects:

- send a document to the checker as the body of a POST (in this example, the current doc)
- tell the checker to format its results as JSON (`out=json`)
- make `text/html;charset=utf-8` the media type of the POST body you send to the checker

The checker also supports `multipart/form-data` for giving it the HTML source to be checked, but giving it the source as a POST body instead  is the preferred (and better) way for doing it.

If instead of using `fetch()` you want to use JQuery `$.ajax(…)`, here’s an example:

```js
var checkerUrl = "http://localhost:8888/?out=json"
$.get(document.location.href,
function(htmlSource)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: checkerUrl,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: htmlSource,
        contentType: "text/html;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonOutput) {
            console.dir(jsonOutput.messages);
        }
    });
});
```

And if instead of either `fetch()` or JQuery `$.ajax(…)` you want to use old-school XHR but it’s not clear how to handle the details in that case, let me know and I can post an example of that too.

In all cases, the `.messages` JSON output is an array of objects that each contain something like:

```
firstColumn: 1
lastColumn: 6
lastLine: 4
message: "Unclosed element “span”."
type: "error"
```

[The documentation for the checker JSON format](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Output-%C2%BB-JSON) gives more details of the JSON the checker emits.